# How to create a connection to mongoDB database with mongoose automatically

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

Hello everyone I want to create a connection to mongoDB database with the help of mongoose without writing repeatedly **mongod** in CLI. Please anyone help to sort this problem.

Comment: "mongod" in the "CLI"? what language is this, shell/bash?

Comment: This means I am connected to the MongoDB database when I write  **monogod** in terminal without this I not connect to database.

Answer (score 0):

```
await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_database');
```

This is how you connect to mongdb using mongoose.
For details you can check this out
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose